SwiftUI: How to create a flowing text with multiple tappable links without compiler errors?
I'm trying to create a Terms and Policy view in SwiftUI that contains flowing text with multiple tappable links. I want the text to wrap naturally like a single paragraph, but also have clickable portions. Here's what I've tried:
struct TermsAndPolicyView: View {
    @Binding var agree: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing:8) {
            CheckBox(isChecked: $agree)
            Text("I have read and I agree to the ")
                .foregroundColor(.Grey666)
            + Text("Privacy Policy")
                .foregroundColor(.primaryColor)
                .underline()
                .onTapGesture{
                    debugPrint(1)
                }
            + Text(" ")
            + Text("Term & Condition")
                .foregroundColor(.primaryColor)
                .underline()
                .onTapGesture{
                    debugPrint(2)
                }
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 32, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 0))
    }
}

However, this code results in the following compiler error:
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

How can I achieve this flowing text effect with multiple tappable links without triggering the compiler error?
Is there a simpler or more efficient way to create this kind of layout in SwiftUI?
Are there any best practices or common patterns for creating such complex text layouts with interactive elements in SwiftUI?


The .onTapGesture(...) modifier returns some View so the compiler is unable append text to it.  You can do create markdown links in the text and capture the OpenURLAction:  Group {         + Text("[Privacy Policy](privacyPolicy)")         + Text("[Term & Condition](tos)")     }     .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in         switch (url.absoluteString) {             case "privacyPolicy":                 break             case "tos":                 break             default:                 break         }         return .handled     })

it work!!!Nice,thank u~
